# Invoke a python method from perl

Tags: python, perl

I have been trying to invoke a method of a python class from perl and is as below

parser.py

```
Class ABC(object):
  def __init__(self, input_file, output_file):
     ....

  def method1(self):
     ....
```

I want to Invoke this method abc from a perl script. The logic is

```
obj = ABC(input_file, output_file)
obj. method1()
```

Tried something like below in perl but in vain

```
use Inline Python => <<"END_OF_PYTHON_CODE";

from parser import ABC
END_OF_PYTHON_CODE
```

It throws error that ImportError: No module named parser

Can someone help me here?

Comment: You should probably go back and accept some answers to your previous questions

Comment: Done. Earlier I didn't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked within inline python ,they provides example code like this: does it work?
Please check if parser.py is in your PYTHONPATH.

```
 use Inline Python;

   my $obj = new Myclass;

   __END__
   __Python__

   from mylibrary import myclass as Myclass
```

Comment: That doen't seem to work and throws the error "Missing right curly or square bracket at abc.pm line 160, at end of line"

Comment: Count your curly brackets then. You're missing a closing bracket.

Comment: All the braces seem to be fine.